# Unable to create an object of type '<dbcontext>'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having an issue creating my first migration in my project which is Identity Server.

I get the following error when running `add-migration initialcreate`

> Unable to create an object of type 'dbcontext'. For the different
> patterns supported at design time

Looking online, it seems I need to create a class which inherits from `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

Below is my context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Todos> ToDos { get; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
        }

        
    }
```

Next is my DesignTime class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=blog.db");

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

The issue I have is `ApplicationDbContext` expects two parameters, and I'm unsure how I can pass in the `IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions`

Comment: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via dependency injection, as long as you have that configured?

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        protected IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> _storeOptions;
        public ApplicationDbContextFactory(IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
        {
            _storeOptions = operationalStoreOptions;
        }
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=blog.db");

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options, _storeOptions);
        }
    }
```